# Can I achieve this layout using CSS floats?

Tags: html, css, css-float

Like a lot of front-end developers I've met in my career, I understanding HTML, CSS, and JavaScript at a proficient level, but the finer points of CSS floats are still my Achilles' heel.

My most recent project has a simple layout that looks like a perfect candidate for improving my understanding of floats. It's trivial to achieve with absolute positioning, but I'd like to determine whether floats can accomplish the same.

Here's a simplified mockup of the desired layout:

[image: simple mockup]

I set up a JSBin example as a good starting point:

http://jsbin.com/UPUzUWU/1/edit?html,css,output

I've spent about 20 minutes playing around with which boxes are floated, how they're floated, which are cleared, how they're cleared, and even the ordering of the HTML. I've gotten kind of close, but no cigar.

Is anyone able to make this work without resorting to absolute positioning (reordering HTML is OK if needed)? If so, can you also do your best to explain the principles behind it?

Thanks!

---

**Edit:**

Sorry, I should have clarified - while reordering the HTML for the boxes is fine, I'd rather not combine multiple boxes into common parent elements. Please assume that semantically, these will all hold content in the same level of the layout hierarchy (i.e., they're all semantic siblings), so ideally they won't share non-semantic parent elements that only exist for the purposes of simplifying styling.

Also, that approach allows for simply floating three elements left, which is too basic a solution to cast more light on how floats work.

Comment: Can the html be changed ? for example: box 1 and box 2 wrapped in a div ?

Comment: If you can change HTML to add container: http://jsbin.com/UPUzUWU/6/edit

Comment: I'm assuming all the divs have to be in one parent element? If not one solution would be to create 3 columns, with 2 divs stacked in the left and right columns then a single div in the center.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/UPUzUWU/9/edit  (just one float, no html structure changes, but... negative margins :))

Comment: Thanks, all - yes, I should have mentioned that I'd prefer not to change the structure of the HTML by adding parent elements. Will update the question now.

Comment: @jd182: Thanks! That's the closest I've see so far to what I'm trying to achieve; would still be good to determine if it's possibly without the use of negative margins.

Comment: Can we change the sequence of div's ?

Comment: @Ani: Yeah, that's fine. Ordering isn't really significant, it's just adding new HTML containers that seems non-semantic to me.

Comment: Hi, can I use "clear" property?

Comment: @amaro: Of course! To be clear, I'm not trying to make this an artificially constrained exercise - I'm just trying to see if it's possible to construct this type of layout using floats instead of absolute positioning, which has been my usual go-to. In the process, I'm hoping to better understand the nuances of floats.

Answer (score 3):

Here: http://jsbin.com/UPUzUWU/11/edit

```
 <div class="box-holder">
    <div class="vertdiv">
     <div class="box box-1 box-square">1</div>
     <div class="box box-2 box-square">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box box-3 box-tall">3</div>
    <div class="vertdiv">
      <div class="box box-4 box-square">4</div>
      <div class="box box-5 box-square">5</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.vertdiv{
   float:left;
 }

 .box-tall {
   float: left;
   height: 200px;
 }
```

**Using Percentage:** http://jsbin.com/UPUzUWU/13/edit

**CSS**

```
.box-square {
   width:100%;
   height: 50%;
 }

 .box-tall {
    float:left;
    height: 100%;
    width:34%;
 }

 .vertdiv{
   float:left;
   width:33%;
   height:100%;
 }
```

Comment: Great!, can you do it with  `%`  instead of pixels ?

Comment: Yes...I can...Hold on

Comment: @Ani: Thanks very much for your answer! Please see my edit above - would prefer to avoid the use of additional parent elements.

Comment: People like you make StackOverflow worth !

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full height & width and fully responsive solution: http://jsbin.com/upAFigEp/2/edit

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Sergei! Please see my clarification to the question - I'd prefer to avoid the use of non-semantic parent elements. Fluid/responsive layout is great but not a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/siva_hari/cg3w7/1/).

```
    .box-holder {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}

.box-square {
  height: 100px;
}

.box-tall {
  height: 200px;
}

.box-1 {
  background-color: #eee;
  float:left;
}

.box-2 {
  background-color: #ddd;
    float:left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
}

.box-3 {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.box-4 {
  background-color: #bbb;
}

.box-5 {
  background-color: #aaa;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Siva - but this still relies on absolute positioning for .box-2. Is there a way to avoid that?